# Audit questions designed to test the reviewer

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Reviewers are banned from reviewing for a certain period of time if they get too many audit questions wrong on StackOverflow. Just out of curiosity, whenever an audit question is asked and the user is unable to determine or not exactly sure if the question response he's about to give will lead to a failed audit, he can simply open that question in a new tab and see if it's a review question and what response is appropriate. Is this possibly a loophole in the system?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're right, this is a way to deal with audits. If you aren't sure, you can also just skip the audit.

**This is not a loophole in the system.** If you're paying enough attention that you aren't sure what choice to make, and you open the question in a new window, then the audit is doing its job.

The main point of audits is to stop people from clicking "Looks OK" on every single question just to raise their reviewing stats and maybe get some badges - to stop the robo-reviewers. It isn't necessarily meant to be some sort of challenging test to make sure that only the best reviewers are reviewing and the others get banned.

Comment: That makes sense. However if you skip a question, it does not get added to your review stats, does it? So if I look at a question/answer to be reviewed and know its an audit, I open it in a new tab irrespective of whether I am paying attention or not I see that particular answer/question is deleted/up-voted, I know what response to give and that reflects in my review stats. So isn't this kind of a jail break?

Comment: @Aditya again, you are paying more attention than hitting "looks ok" when you do that. You are stepping over the *intentially* low bar that separates you from robo reviewers. That you (as a human) can do this in many ways is all that audits are supposed to test.